# MySQL Query Concerning Average of Rows Greater than Median in Group

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a problem trying to figure out the following and not even 100% sure if this task can be done from pure mysql query alone.

I need to select rows that share the same ID and Type while keeping track of their TimeStamps.

```
SELECT ObjectId, TimeStamp, Count(ObjectId) As theCount FROM 
   (Select ObjectId, TimeStamp, RelationType, ObjectType From Table
      Group By ObjectId, TimeStamp) As tmp
      WHERE RelationType = 'A'
      AND ObjectType = 'B'
      GROUP By ObjectId
      HAVING Count(ObjectId) >= 0 ORDER By theCount DESC
```

The part of finding and counting the number of rows that are similar enough for me to select is easy but I am having trouble with the next part.

I need to keep track of all the TimeStamps after the median TimeStamp and get the average of those TimeStamps above the median TimeStamp. I need to get the average of those TimeStamps above their Median so I can order them DESC.

If my question is not clear enough or any questions please post so I can return a comment. I have spent many hours trying to different ways to achieving my goal but the only code that I feel is correct is the posted query above.

The below code is where I am right now. I am getting the average of all the grouped items but like I said I only need the average of the TimeStamps above the group median.

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT ObjectId, PostDate, Count(ObjectId) AS Count, AVG(TimeStamp) AS Average
   FROM (Select ObjectId, TimeStamp, RelationType, ObjectType 
      FROM Relations Group By ObjectId, TimeStamp
   ) As tmp
WHERE RelationType = 'A' AND ObjectType = 'B'
GROUP By ObjectId HAVING Count(ObjectId) >= 1
AND AVG(TimeStamp) > MIN(TimeStamp)
ORDER By Count DESC ) AS tmp2 ORDER BY Average DESC, Count LIMIT 10

            RETURNS:

            ObjectId: 112717 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151030188390.5
            ObjectId: 166047 // Count: 4 // Average: 20151023363026.25
            ObjectId: 166312 // Count: 3 // Average: 20151022171454.332
            ObjectId: 166309 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151022170765.5
            ObjectId: 166307 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151022170765.5
            ObjectId: 165163 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151021188390.5
            ObjectId: 133214 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151021188388
            ObjectId: 165164 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151021188388
            ObjectId: 165831 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151021184532.5
            ObjectId: 165822 // Count: 2 // Average: 20151021184532.5
```

Comment: maybe post sample input/output data or link to sqlfiddle